# State of the the ng-form within a directive does not propagate to an outer form

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

I have a myNumber directive that contains a couple of nested ng-forms around an input. The input has the ng-required attribute set to true and a certain ng-pattern. The thing is that the state of the input (e.g. ng-valid-required, ng-invalid-pattern) propagates to the ng-forms inside the directive. So they get to have the same state as the input itself, which is the wanted behavior. But, once outside the directive itself, the ng-form around the directive does not get the state of the ng-forms within.

```
<ng-form name="outerForm" id="outerForm">
    <my-number ...></my-number>
</ng-form>
```

While the input and the ng-forms inside directive have a state like ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-pattern, the outerForm is ng-pristine ng-valid.

Is this normal behavior, is this how AngularJS works, or is there a workaround to get the state outside of a directive?

Comment: Does your `my-number` directive has an isolated scope?

Comment: Yes, it has an isolated scope. It looks like this: scope: {appModel: '=', field: '=', formReadonly: '=', idx: '='}

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue, but fail to do so. Here is a plunker, it seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/jUpmSxjDuNQCzpoOnmSv?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for that. But the directive's template is dynamically built in the link function (using element.wrap, element.append, element.attr) and then $compile it's called on the element. Maybe here's the issue.

Comment: Could you show the code in your directive or setup a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue using the controller function the following way:

```
      controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('innerForm.$valid', function() {
                if ($scope.innerForm.$valid) {
                    $scope.$parent.outerForm.$setValidity(null, true);
                } else {
                    $scope.$parent.outerForm.$setValidity(null, false);
                }
            });
        }
```